# Bottema Triangle proof

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $BM$ and $CN$ be  external bisectors of angles $\angle B=12°$ and $\angle C=132°$ of a special triangle $\triangle ABC$, each terminated at the opposite side .Without using trigonometric functions, compare the length of the angle bisectors.

I think I can't guess the figure. I need a bit of help. Please help me.

Comment: You might just formulate a question in the title.

Comment: @TVSuchty Sorry I could not understand...What you mean by the comment

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is a special triangle? How do you "terminate at the opposite side" if these are external  bisectors? You probably should include a diagram. Does this have something to do with Bottema's Theorem (which I just had to look up)?

Comment: @user606630 Just formulate an actual question in the title.

Comment: Whatever it is .There is no other meaning by the word special triangle . It here means that the triangle is unique whose features I have mentioned above. I too have the same doubt as to how the external bisectors meet their opposite side? So I failed in drawing the diagram. I got it in a textbook without any diagrammatic aid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exact drawing of your triangle. Determine all angles you can see and write the values into the figure. At the end you shall immediately see what is the relation between the two lengths in question.

[image]